# Corosync resource keeps moving after failed node is online again

Tags: pacemaker, corosync

I have a 2-node corosync cluster managing a virtual IP and an asterisk resource. When I shutdown one of the nodes (server2) intentionally (as a disaster recovery test), the first node (server1) takes over asterisk instantly.

However, when server2 has booted, it appears that the asterisk instance on server1 is no longer running on server1, neither is it running on server2. I prefer that it remains at the running server at all times. The virtual_ip didn't move, which is okay.

I've tried setting stickinessparameters on both nodes (same value), but that doesn't seem to help.

```
pcs resource meta asterisk resource-stickiness=100
```

and

```
pcs resource meta asterisk resource-stickiness=INFINITY
```

Also, the parameter "start-failure-is-fatal" is set to false, to make sure that whatever is keeping server2 from starting up asterisk, to try again, but that doesn't have any effect either. Setting quorumparameters also have no effect:

```
pcs property set stonith-enabled=false
pcs property set no-quorum-policy=ignore
pcs property set start-failure-is-fatal=false
```

Here is my general config.

```
totem {
  version: 2
  cluster_name: astcluster
  secauth: off
  join: 30
  consensus: 300
  vsftype: none
  max_messages: 20
  rrp_mode: none
  interface {
    member {
      memberaddr: 192.168.83.133
    }
    member {
      memberaddr: 192.168.83.135
    }
    ringnumber: 0
    bindnetaddr: 192.168.83.0
    mcastport: 5405
  }
  transport: udpu
}

nodelist {
  node {
    ring0_addr: astp5.internal.uzgent.be
    nodeid: 1
    quorum_votes: 1
  }
  node {
    ring0_addr: astp6.internal.uzgent.be
    nodeid: 2
    quorum_votes: 1
  }
}

quorum {
  provider: corosync_votequorum
  two_node: 1
  wait_for_all: 0
  expected_votes: 1
}


logging {
  to_logfile: yes
  logfile: /var/log/cluster/corosync.log
  to_syslog: no
  debug: off
  timestamp: on
}
```

Can someone tell me how to handle this?

EDIT, attached the pacemaker config.

```
<cib crm_feature_set="3.0.10" validate-with="pacemaker-2.3" epoch="43" num_updates="0" admin_epoch="0" cib-last-written="Thu Feb 23 14:56:07 2017" update-origin="server2" update-client="crm_attribute" update-user="root" have-quorum="1" dc-uuid="1">
  <configuration>
    <crm_config>
      <cluster_property_set id="cib-bootstrap-options">
        <nvpair id="cib-bootstrap-options-stonith-enabled" name="stonith-enabled" value="false"/>
        <nvpair id="cib-bootstrap-options-no-quorum-policy" name="no-quorum-policy" value="ignore"/>
        <nvpair id="cib-bootstrap-options-have-watchdog" name="have-watchdog" value="false"/>
        <nvpair id="cib-bootstrap-options-dc-version" name="dc-version" value="1.1.13-10.el7-44eb2dd"/>
        <nvpair id="cib-bootstrap-options-cluster-infrastructure" name="cluster-infrastructure" value="corosync"/>
        <nvpair id="cib-bootstrap-options-cluster-name" name="cluster-name" value="astcluster"/>
        <nvpair id="cib-bootstrap-options-last-lrm-refresh" name="last-lrm-refresh" value="1487858117"/>
        <nvpair id="cib-bootstrap-options-start-failure-is-fatal" name="start-failure-is-fatal" value="false"/>
      </cluster_property_set>
    </crm_config>
    <nodes>
      <node id="1" uname="server1"/>
      <node id="2" uname="server2">
        <instance_attributes id="nodes-2"/>
      </node>
    </nodes>
    <resources>
      <primitive class="ocf" id="virtual_ip" provider="heartbeat" type="IPaddr2">
        <instance_attributes id="virtual_ip-instance_attributes">
          <nvpair id="virtual_ip-instance_attributes-ip" name="ip" value="192.168.83.137"/>
          <nvpair id="virtual_ip-instance_attributes-cidr_netmask" name="cidr_netmask" value="32"/>
        </instance_attributes>
        <operations>
          <op id="virtual_ip-start-interval-0s" interval="0s" name="start" timeout="20s"/>
          <op id="virtual_ip-stop-interval-0s" interval="0s" name="stop" timeout="20s"/>
          <op id="virtual_ip-monitor-interval-30s" interval="30s" name="monitor"/>
        </operations>
      </primitive>
      <primitive class="ocf" id="asterisk" provider="heartbeat" type="asterisk">
        <instance_attributes id="asterisk-instance_attributes">
          <nvpair id="asterisk-instance_attributes-user" name="user" value="asterisk"/>
          <nvpair id="asterisk-instance_attributes-group" name="group" value="asterisk"/>
        </instance_attributes>
        <meta_attributes id="asterisk-meta_attributes">
          <nvpair id="asterisk-meta_attributes-is-managed" name="is-managed" value="true"/>
          <nvpair id="asterisk-meta_attributes-expected-quorum-votes" name="expected-quorum-votes" value="1"/>
          <nvpair id="asterisk-meta_attributes-resource-stickiness" name="resource-stickiness" value="INFINITY"/>
          <nvpair id="asterisk-meta_attributes-default-resource-stickiness" name="default-resource-stickiness" value="1000"/>
        </meta_attributes>
        <operations>
          <op id="asterisk-start-interval-0s" interval="0s" name="start" timeout="20"/>
          <op id="asterisk-stop-interval-0s" interval="0s" name="stop" timeout="20"/>
          <op id="asterisk-monitor-interval-60s" interval="60s" name="monitor" timeout="30"/>
        </operations>
      </primitive>
    </resources>
    <constraints/>
  </configuration>
  <status>
    <node_state id="2" uname="server2" in_ccm="true" crmd="online" crm-debug-origin="do_update_resource" join="member" expected="member">
      <transient_attributes id="2">
        <instance_attributes id="status-2">
          <nvpair id="status-2-shutdown" name="shutdown" value="0"/>
          <nvpair id="status-2-probe_complete" name="probe_complete" value="true"/>
          <nvpair id="status-2-last-failure-asterisk" name="last-failure-asterisk" value="1487845098"/>
        </instance_attributes>
      </transient_attributes>
      <lrm id="2">
        <lrm_resources>
          <lrm_resource id="virtual_ip" type="IPaddr2" class="ocf" provider="heartbeat">
            <lrm_rsc_op id="virtual_ip_last_0" operation_key="virtual_ip_monitor_0" operation="monitor" crm-debug-origin="do_update_resource" crm_feature_set="3.0.10" transition-key="7:59:7:8e6dd4d3-49ed-4e78-92b9-ec440e36f949" transition-magic="0:7;7:59:7:8e6dd4d3-49ed-4e78-92b9-ec440e36f949" on_node="server2" call-id="5" rc-code="7" op-status="0" interval="0" last-run="1487845098" last-rc-change="1487845098" exec-time="68" queue-time="0" op-digest="7ea42b08d9415fb0dbbde15977130035"/>
          </lrm_resource>
          <lrm_resource id="asterisk" type="asterisk" class="ocf" provider="heartbeat">
            <lrm_rsc_op id="asterisk_last_failure_0" operation_key="asterisk_monitor_0" operation="monitor" crm-debug-origin="do_update_resource" crm_feature_set="3.0.10" transition-key="6:79:7:8e6dd4d3-49ed-4e78-92b9-ec440e36f949" transition-magic="0:0;6:79:7:8e6dd4d3-49ed-4e78-92b9-ec440e36f949" on_node="server2" call-id="22" rc-code="0" op-status="0" interval="0" last-run="1487858116" last-rc-change="1487858116" exec-time="47" queue-time="0" op-digest="337a6295a6acbbd18616daf0206c3394"/>
            <lrm_rsc_op id="asterisk_last_0" operation_key="asterisk_stop_0" operation="stop" crm-debug-origin="do_update_resource" crm_feature_set="3.0.10" transition-key="9:82:0:8e6dd4d3-49ed-4e78-92b9-ec440e36f949" transition-magic="0:0;9:82:0:8e6dd4d3-49ed-4e78-92b9-ec440e36f949" on_node="server2" call-id="25" rc-code="0" op-status="0" interval="0" last-run="1487858128" last-rc-change="1487858128" exec-time="1036" queue-time="0" op-digest="337a6295a6acbbd18616daf0206c3394" op-secure-params=" user " op-secure-digest="cf2187fe855553314a7a6bc14ff18918"/>
            <lrm_rsc_op id="asterisk_monitor_60000" operation_key="asterisk_monitor_60000" operation="monitor" crm-debug-origin="do_update_resource" crm_feature_set="3.0.10" transition-key="10:80:0:8e6dd4d3-49ed-4e78-92b9-ec440e36f949" transition-magic="0:0;10:80:0:8e6dd4d3-49ed-4e78-92b9-ec440e36f949" on_node="server2" call-id="23" rc-code="0" op-status="0" interval="60000" last-rc-change="1487858116" exec-time="47" queue-time="0" op-digest="ce41237c2113b12d51aaed8af6b8a09f" op-secure-params=" user " op-secure-digest="cf2187fe855553314a7a6bc14ff18918"/>
          </lrm_resource>
        </lrm_resources>
      </lrm>
    </node_state>
    <node_state id="1" uname="server1" in_ccm="true" crmd="online" crm-debug-origin="do_update_resource" join="member" expected="member">
      <transient_attributes id="1">
        <instance_attributes id="status-1">
          <nvpair id="status-1-shutdown" name="shutdown" value="0"/>
          <nvpair id="status-1-probe_complete" name="probe_complete" value="true"/>
        </instance_attributes>
      </transient_attributes>
      <lrm id="1">
        <lrm_resources>
          <lrm_resource id="virtual_ip" type="IPaddr2" class="ocf" provider="heartbeat">
            <lrm_rsc_op id="virtual_ip_last_0" operation_key="virtual_ip_start_0" operation="start" crm-debug-origin="build_active_RAs" crm_feature_set="3.0.10" transition-key="7:6:0:b7b79be6-bb63-4f56-b425-fc84e90ef38b" transition-magic="0:0;7:6:0:b7b79be6-bb63-4f56-b425-fc84e90ef38b" on_node="server1" call-id="10" rc-code="0" op-status="0" interval="0" last-run="1487838677" last-rc-change="1487838677" exec-time="47" queue-time="0" op-digest="7ea42b08d9415fb0dbbde15977130035"/>
            <lrm_rsc_op id="virtual_ip_monitor_30000" operation_key="virtual_ip_monitor_30000" operation="monitor" crm-debug-origin="build_active_RAs" crm_feature_set="3.0.10" transition-key="7:7:0:b7b79be6-bb63-4f56-b425-fc84e90ef38b" transition-magic="0:0;7:7:0:b7b79be6-bb63-4f56-b425-fc84e90ef38b" on_node="server1" call-id="12" rc-code="0" op-status="0" interval="30000" last-rc-change="1487838679" exec-time="34" queue-time="0" op-digest="e81e10104a53c2ccab94a6935229ae08"/>
          </lrm_resource>
          <lrm_resource id="asterisk" type="asterisk" class="ocf" provider="heartbeat">
            <lrm_rsc_op id="asterisk_last_0" operation_key="asterisk_start_0" operation="start" crm-debug-origin="do_update_resource" crm_feature_set="3.0.10" transition-key="10:82:0:8e6dd4d3-49ed-4e78-92b9-ec440e36f949" transition-magic="0:0;10:82:0:8e6dd4d3-49ed-4e78-92b9-ec440e36f949" on_node="server1" call-id="77" rc-code="0" op-status="0" interval="0" last-run="1487858129" last-rc-change="1487858129" exec-time="2517" queue-time="0" op-digest="337a6295a6acbbd18616daf0206c3394" op-secure-params=" user " op-secure-digest="cf2187fe855553314a7a6bc14ff18918"/>
            <lrm_rsc_op id="asterisk_monitor_60000" operation_key="asterisk_monitor_60000" operation="monitor" crm-debug-origin="do_update_resource" crm_feature_set="3.0.10" transition-key="11:82:0:8e6dd4d3-49ed-4e78-92b9-ec440e36f949" transition-magic="0:0;11:82:0:8e6dd4d3-49ed-4e78-92b9-ec440e36f949" on_node="server1" call-id="78" rc-code="0" op-status="0" interval="60000" last-rc-change="1487858132" exec-time="46" queue-time="0" op-digest="ce41237c2113b12d51aaed8af6b8a09f" op-secure-params=" user " op-secure-digest="cf2187fe855553314a7a6bc14ff18918"/>
          </lrm_resource>
        </lrm_resources>
      </lrm>
    </node_state>
  </status>
</cib>
```

EDIT: also tried to add some colocation constraints

```
[root@server1]# pcs constraint show
Location Constraints:
Ordering Constraints:
  Resource Sets:
    set virtual_ip asterisk
Colocation Constraints:
  virtual_ip with asterisk (score:INFINITY)
```

EDIT: Found a solution! Had to add the following parameter to the asterisk resource: on-fail=fence

Comment: You're likely missing constraints keeping the IP and the asterisk service running together. What does your Pacemaker configuration look like? # pcs cluster cib

Comment: @MattKereczman
I have attached the pacemaker config.

Comment: Tried keeping them together by creating a group, but that doesn't seem to work.
    pcs resource group add asteriskgroup virtual_ip asterisk

Comment: I don't see any fence agents defined in your cluster, so I don't think that's an actual fix. Maybe you just needed to clean up some failed actions in your cluster. I would try to figure those things out; an HA cluster that isn't configured correctly will come back to bite you.

Comment: The questions is fine on a technical level, but if this is an attempt to create an Asterisk cluster you are on the wrong path.  Search serverfault for 'asterisk cluster' and you'll see that you are tackling only the simplest part of the problem.  Failure detection, sync only between healthy peers, handling of dual-active contention, allowing for common & unique dialplan components by peer, etc. aren't handled.  If you want something really simply look at DRBD to accomplish the same as coro.  DBDB/corosync are not suitable for production Asterisk cluster, but ok for experiment/home use.

Comment: @MattKereczman
Thanks for your suggestion, I'll have a closer look. Been testing for a few hours and it does seem to failover correctly. After the server is up again, I always remember to do a cleanup.

Comment: @TSG
You're right, it's very difficult to handle all of these things but these asterisk instances will only be used for some queues and conferences and will not have any client endpoints. Our main asterisk servers are behind some F5 BIGIP loadbalancers, so we aren't making any concessions there. I'll look for some monitoring scripts to make sure these points are covered. Thanks!

Comment: One big drawback to corosync (or DRBD, or NFS/SMB share) is file corruption by one client immediately corrupts the other.  If you are only handling queues and conferences you may wish to not sync any files.  Just let cluster manager handle complete failure of a node.   Of course, if Asterisk process is alive but not bridging calls (another fun way Asterisk fails) your cluster will also not failover.  Not to discourage you - but the simple 'unplug the node' test is dangerously simplistic for production clusters.

Answer (score 0):

Did you happen move the resource to the given node before you stopped it?   If you move a resource manually, behind the scenes, the cluster resource manager creates a location constraint for that resource for the given node.   I don't see this constraint in your configuration XML, but it could be that you captured that configuration before you moved the resource.

I had this very same problem.   After I used 'crm resource unmove ' to give control back to the cluster resource manager, recovering a node no longer resulted in the resource getting moved back to the original node.

See the following documentation for details.

http://clusterlabs.org/doc/en-US/Pacemaker/1.1-plugin/html/Clusters_from_Scratch/_manually_moving_resources_around_the_cluster.html